# How to Solder RN-42 to a Breakout Board

Tags: arduino, bluetooth, datalogger

I have an RN-42 Bluetooth module (without any of the breakout boards), and I would like to use the RN-42 for data logging (e.g. temperature, humidity etc) via Bluetooth.

What components do I need and how do I go about soldering the RN-42 onto a breakout board?

Comment: Did you read the datasheet of RN-42 Bluetooth module? What about application notes?

Answer (score 6):

You need a soldering iron and [this guide to soldering castellated vias](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/how-to-solder-castellated-mounting-holes/all), a relatively straightforward process.  It's unclear from your question if you are trying to solder it to a purpose-made breakout board or a generic one but it doesn't look like the edge vias are on standard 0.1" pitch, so you will almost certainly need to obtain a suitable breakout board from somewhere.

Comment: This guide is excellent! Very high quality images.

Comment: @Uwe all except the recommendation to use rubbing alcohol ... rubbing alcohol contains oil, so it should not be used ... use isopropyl alcohol instead

Comment: @jsotola That may be a regional thing. Here in the US, "rubbing alcohol" just refers to either isopropyl alcohol or denatured ethanol for use as an antiseptic; I've never heard of it containing oil of any sort.

Comment: @jsotola are you British? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubbing_alcohol

Answer (score 2):

Aside from the physical soldering, you will find that the bare minimum parts needed to use the module to be 3.3V power (typical),a common ground and the tx/rx signals. That's it. It is not 5V friendly, so you may need level translators. But many microcontrollers can work on 3.3V with minimal difference so that may not be necessary.

Everything else on most breakout boards are just convenient status leds and a 5v to 3.3v regulator.